# Regarding nawk and system command

Tags: awk, solaris, ksh, nawk

I am working on Solaris and working on a script that turns on any disabled service .
Here is the output file:

```
disabled        7:22:05 svc:/network/bla-bla:default
online         Jun_14   svc:/network/blu-blu:default
```

I would like my code to parse this and turn the disabled one on using nawk itself

Here is what I have tried by it doesn't work for some reason:

```
cat output | nawk '/disabled/ {system(svcadm enable $3)}'
```

here is the output it gives:

```
**sh: line 1: svc:/network/bla-bla:default: not found**
```

The output i need on `cat output |grep bl*` is :

```
online        7:22:05 svc:/network/bla-bla:default
online         Jun_14   svc:/network/blu-blu:default
```

Can anyone explain to me why this happens and how to make this nawk work. All I want is

```
svcadm enable svc:/network/bla-bla:default
```

to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's treating `svcadm` as a variable name, which has no value.  Try

```
 nawk '{system("svcadm enable " $3)}'
```

(Sorry, I meant that as the nawk program -- corrected now.)

Comment: It doesn't work yet.. it now throws the error "sh: line 1: 0: not found"

Comment: I got it !!! the plus was the problem since its not a string concatenator in shell scripts ....Thank you for this. If u can correct the answer I will go ahead n mark it right